# Joomla 2.5. - Setup stuck on configuration step 6

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to setup joomla on a shared windows 2008 server.  PHP version is 5.2 FastCGI.  As per joomla pre-installation check the host meets all the requirements.  But setup gets stuck on the step 6 (configuration).  It is just showing the progress update, but not doing anything.

[image: Pre Installation check]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution at this link http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=623&t=581196

**Edited: Here is the solution posted @joomla.org forum. All credit goes to rickpowers01**

You all seem to be on the right track but not very clear. Here is what I did when the installer stalled at step 6. First, understand what the installer is trying to do: It is composing a file called configuration.php that must reside at your site root. It fails because your ISP setup does not let your web user write to the httpdocs directory.

The good news is that you can create and edit this file locally and upload it through FTP or the Plesk File Manager. To create it locally unzip the installation package and copy the file called configuration.php-dist to configuration.php. Open it with a free text editor and edit the following parameters:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';    // Normally mysql
public $host = 'yourdomain.com';     // This is normally set to localhost - no! - put in your real domain name 
public $user = 'root';   // MySQL username - whatever you entered on the installer dialog step 4
public $password = 'your db password';  // MySQL password - whatever you entered on the installer dialog step 4
public $db = 'your db name';     // MySQL database name -whatever you entered on the installer dialog step 4
public $dbprefix = 'xxxx_';  // Do not change unless you need to! -whatever you entered on the installer dialog step 4
```

Save and upload the file to the root of your website. Remove the installation directory. Try yourdomain/administrator and you should get the login. If you get SQL errors then check your db parameters with the phpadmin tool on plesk. Redit configuration.php and reupload.

If you got to step 6 then the database should have been created and these parameters should be what you put into the database creation dialogue. If this doesnt work then check that the database exists and and table names start with the prefix etc.

Comment: Would be nice to post the solution also here, so that other users won't have to read tons of forum posts. Thanks.

Comment: Done, posted the solution